# REST api : correctly ask for an action

Tags: api, rest, endpoint

I'm currently working on a REST api. I've read a few times how to handle endpoints the right way, using the protocol (post, put, ...) to define which action should be made.

Let's say I have a list of quotes. I have :

- a GET endpoint /quotes that let me get all my quotes
- a POST /quote to post a new quote
- a GET /quotes/ID to get a single quote
- a PUT /quote/ID to update a quote.

Now I want to add the ability to :

- share a quote with another member
- mark a quote as favorite
- unmark

What endpoint should I use for that? /quote/ID/share seems to be a terrible idea. I have thought of a POST to /quote/ID with an "action" parameter that tells the script what action to perform on the quote, would that be correct?

Comment: How is acting? Please describe what a "member" is. Are members REST resources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to separate API from your application logic. From API you GET the quote and API from now on shouldn't care what you do with that data. The same with marking quotes as favorites. It's your application's and user db's problem how to mark something. Again, API should care only about properly answering to you GETs.

Think about REST API as a database--you GET data from there, you can PUT or POST some data, but things like sharing or marking should be done in application.

**Edit**

About endpoints.

- `GET/POST/PUT /quote[s]` should care only about quotes;
- `PUT/POST /user/{userId}/action` with POST data like `{"type": "share", "target": "otherUserId", "quoteId": 123}` could be used for saving *data about actions* in DB.

Comment: Could you perhaps elaborate more?

Comment: @mef, should I dive in more details?

Comment: I think giving example endpoints he may use for his specific use case would be helpful.

Comment: Hey, and thanks for your response ! Sure, sharing as you think about sharing with facebook friends is client side, but that's not what I thought : I have a table linking quotes to users, and users can "send" quotes to other users in their friendlist, creating an entry in the database. The same thing is valid for marking as favorite, it updates an entry in the database. So I do need the server to take care of this, and so a route to call to let it know to take care of this.

Comment: Why not create shares as en entity as well?

Comment: Thanks for the improved answer. I would really want to know why would you use the /users endpoint in place of the /quotes, since this applies only on quotes, and I absolutely don't need my user ID to be part of the endpoint (user is already identified using Oauth2). Wouldn't it be more valid to use the /quotes endpoint as I suggested, maybe with a /action at the end like you did in your answer ?

Comment: Quotes are like books in library - you can GET them, maybe even make some edits (POST markings with pencil, bad thing), but you don't store information about book readers **in** book. You could better go for separate entity like @Opal suggested - something like "statistics" or some other metadata.